# Unsupported media type Django API

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, postman

I'm new at Django and my project is in REST
when i'm using postman to check URLs it's make this error:

"detail": "Unsupported media type "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryAU1ShXHTHrfcQr61" in request."

and when using curl this error occurred:

{"detail":"JSON parse error - Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)"}

this is my view for an example URL:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def register(request):
    user_data = request.data
    if user_data:
        serializer = UserSerializers(data=user_data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            registerInfo = {
                'name': serializer.validated_data['name'],
                'degImage': serializer.validated_data['degImage'],
            }

             serializer.save(registerInfo)
             return Response({
                "code": 200,
                "status": "successful",
                "message": "code was sent try to validate code"
                })
        else:
            return Response({
                "status": "error",
                "error": "Bad request"
            })
    else:
        return Response({
            "status": "error",
            "error": "Empty request"
        })
```

and this is serializer class:

```
class UserSerializers(serializers.Serializer):
    name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    degImage = serializers.ImageField(required=True)

    def save(self, validated_data):
        user = Users(
            name=validated_data['name'],
            degImage=validated_data['degImage']
        )
        user.save()
        return user
```

and the model:

```
class Users(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    degImage = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, default='detImage')
```

Comment: Please post the code that processes the request. Impossible to guess what is wrong based on only the error message.

Comment: @manassehkatz i didi it

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In postman set, the **body** as **Raw** and select **JSON** from the **drop-down** and send the request.

### or

change the parser in Django rest framework

settings.py

```
 REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
        'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser'
     )
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint! I was deriving from the wrong base parser class!

Comment: I've always found this to be such a pain. Backend development for some reason you always need to try 'form-data', 'form-urlencoded', 'raw', etc to see which one works. And now not only it needs to be raw, but also has to set the language...

Answer (score 3):

You are probably sending your request with a MIME type that your method is not ready to work with. 
Check out the media types in here: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types/Complete_list_of_MIME_types

Can't say much without looking at your request, but i hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
            'rest_framework.parsers.FormParser',
            'rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser',
    ),
}
```